# $P0$ elements for $H1$

Tags: finite-element, finite-difference, finite-volume, discontinuous-galerkin

Are there $P0$ (zero degree/constant element) nonconforming methods for approximating solutions in $H1$? More specifically, I have the equation:

$$u-f - T\Delta u = 0$$

Which can be interpreted as heat diffusion for time $T$ with an implicit step in time. I know that this can easily be handled with CG (continuous Galerkin) or DG (discontinuous Galerkin) as long as I use elements with degree $\geq 1$. I would like to use $P0$ elements however. The main issue is that the gradient in the variational formulation vanishes for constant elements.

Finite differences in some sense achieve this on a regular grid but I have an arbitrary mesh. So references on discretizations of the Laplace operator on discontinuous piecewise constant meshes are also welcome (I mainly deal with the 2D setting).

I am not that familiar with those but maybe finite volume (cell-centered) methods can handle this. I've seen some schemes but those considered equations without a reaction term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Wolfgang Bangerth's answer, I think P0 DG schemes reduce to two-point cell-centered finite volume schemes. I don't know if DG convergence analysis always includes $p = 0$, but the resulting finite volume schemes can be shown to converge under appropriate "mesh orthogonality" conditions.

[https://math.unice.fr/~minjeaud/Donnees/JourneesNumeriques_14-1/TP/Nice2014.pdf](https://math.unice.fr/%7Eminjeaud/Donnees/JourneesNumeriques_14-1/TP/Nice2014.pdf)

Edit: including comment in the main answer. I think TPFA is equivalent to all of the DG methods (SIPG, NIPG, IIPG) for an appropriately defined mesh-dependent penalty parameter. For example, assuming $u$ is constant and $v=1$, all terms in the for SIPG bilinear form drop out except for the penalty term $\sum\tau_f \int_f [u]v = \sum \tau_f |f| (u^+-u)$, which is identical to TPFA if $\tau_f$ is defined as the inverse distance from the cell centers of the elements connected to each face $f$.

Comment: What do you mean by "do reduce to TPFA"? Does TPFA match SIPG, NIPG, or IIPG for specific parameters? The mesh orthogonality is a requirement on TPFA. As far as I am aware there is no such requirement on interior penalty DG, but it can still converge in some cases.

Comment: I think it matches all of them for an appropriately defined mesh-dependent penalty parameter. For example, assuming $u$ is constant and $v=1$, all terms in the for SIPG bilinear form drop out except for the penalty term $ \sum \tau_f \int_{f} [u] v = \sum \tau_f  |f| (u^+-u)$, which is similar to TPFA if $\tau_f$ is defined as the inverse distance from the two cell centers.

Comment: While this is interesting in its own right, it seems more like trying to fit one method to the other artificially, which is not really how things stand in practice (for me). For example one of the main reasons I will likely transition to SIPG is to allow for: 1) higher degrees in an uncomplicated manner, 2) not having the restrictive orthogonality requirement on the mesh. And even then SIPG would supposedly converge to the right solution, or at least that is what I am envisioning.

Comment: Sure. I'm not trying to push TPFA (I actually work in high order DG myself), just trying to explain what you might expect for convergence if you use p=0 and SIPG.

Answer (score 2):

You can use discontinuous Galerkin methods also for $P_0$ elements. It's true that the gradient in the cell interior is zero, so your formulation will exclusively consist of the jump terms at cell interfaces.

Comment: Is there a result on the convergence for P0 elements? What flavor of DG would this work for (e.g. IPG, LDG, etc.)?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't know the literature well enough but would assume that for all of these, using $P_0$ elements converges. (Of course, convergence for these low-order elements might be unbearably and impractically slow, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: From what I have found in literature this seems to be dependent on the mesh, problem, and scheme. The main issue is that if we have $O(h^p)$ then this will not even converge theoretically for $p=0$. For instance NIPG has $O(h^p)$ convergence for even $p$ on arbitrary meshes for the Poisson equation, while SIPG has $O(h^{p+1})$. Some of the results I have found come from here: "Numerical Analysis of Higher Order Discontinuous  Galerkin Finite Element Methods", R. Hartmann.

Comment: In the case of ${\cal O}(h^p)$, when you have $p=0$, you generally *do* converge the error to zero, just not an any particular rate. In other words, you'll get $o(1)$ convergence, which means that the error goes to zero, but not at a rate that would follow a $h^\alpha$.

Comment: I had the impression that $O(1)$ will leave you with a constant error term that will remain regardless of the number of degrees of freedom. For example this behaviour can be seen in Table 4.1 of: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338570266_Sub-optimal_convergence_of_discontinuous_Galerkin_methods_with_central_fluxes_for_even_degree_polynomial_approximations
Am I misunderstanding something regarding DG's error bound?At least for FD schemes I know I can easily construct nonsensical schemes with $O(1)$ that do not converge. Is there a key difference that I am missing?

Comment: That's the difference between big-O $O(1)$ and little-o $o(1)$ :-)

Comment: The a-priori bounds from the error analysis that I linked   are big-O though. Meaning that $P0$ elements may well not converge to anything for specific meshing, equations, and schemes.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that in general, the big-O statement holds except when you have something like $h^0$. Then the little-o holds.

Comment: Is there a proof of the $o(1)$ behaviour? I haven't found such a general result in the references I have read. On the contrary, Table 4.1 in: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338570266_Sub-optimal_convergence_of_discontinuous_Galerkin_methods_with_central_fluxes_for_even_degree_polynomial_approximations suggests that this is not the case (at least for the considered problem and assumptions). That is, the error does not tend to zero regardless of the diameter of the largest element.

Comment: @lightxbulb I don't recall. It will have come out of the interpolation estimate or the L2 result via the Nitsche trick. So while I can't give you a reference, I'm pretty sure that it's true. It should also be relatively easy to try out.